DataLoader forcing batches into __getitem__ of Dataset
I am writing a model for image segmentation and am therefore writing a custom Pytorch Dataset that gets images from huggingface.
This is the implementation of the Dataset that I cut down to the minimum for this question :
class SegmentationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, datacard="skytnt/anime-segmentation", directory="imgs-masks", split="train", transforms=None):
        load_data = load_dataset(datacard, directory, trust_remote_code=True)
        train_set, valid_set, test_set = random_split(load_data["train"], [0.7, 0.2, 0.1])
        self.transforms = transforms
        if split=="train":
            self.dataset = train_set
        if split=="valid":
            self.dataset = valid_set
        if split=="test":
            self.dataset = test_set

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # This function has been cutdown to the minimum for this question
        print(idx)
        print(self.dataset[idx]["image"])
        ...
        return self.dataset[idx]["image"])

For some reason, when passing the Dataset to the DataLoader and iterating on the DataLoader, the getitem was directly getting a batch of elements instead of getting an element.
def getitem(self, idx):
   print(self.dataset[idx]["image"])


[<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=600x784 at
0x782ACE8C77C0>, <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB
size=1972x2877 at 0x782ACE8C6BF0>, <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile
image mode=RGB size=602x825 at 0x782ACE8C4FA0>,
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=636x882 at
0x782ACE8C41C0>]

This is apparently because the idx given by the getitem in parameter is also an array and not the index of one element.
def getitem(self, idx):
    print(idx)


[880, 651, 284, 548, 55, 1099, 377, 768]

Is there a reason why the idx is giving a batch of indexes instead of just an index ? I didn't touch the sampler of the DataLoader.
